Python 3.11: No module named "unittest.mock"
I have tried to run a program using pytorch. It stopped with the error 'No module named "unittest.mock"'
Then I wrote a minimal python program:
import unittest.mock
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello world")

The same error. Documentation in https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock. This module should be builtin since 3.3
Environment: python 3.11.2, Debian-Bookworm
Running in Debian-Bullseye with python 3.9: the same problem

Do you have a package or a module named unittest in the directory you are running this from?

Repair or reinstall Python

In another Debian-Bookworm environment the test code runs. I will reinstall the python3 packages. Only 51 packages (:

Do you have a file unittest.py in your current directory?

Try import unittest; print(unittest) to see what and where the module is.

This tip provides the solution: There is another module ‘unittest’ that has overlaid the built-in module. Thank you wjandrea!

The program "import unittest; print(unittest)" shows the location of an (unexpected) self written module "unittest".
That module has blocked the builtin module.
Thanks to wjandrea!

If you see "No modue named 'unittestmock'" when unning PyTorch, your Python might be old o set up rong. Make sre you're on Python 3.3 or ewe, check your setngs, and use a virtual environent. Even though unittest.mock is old now, you can still use it. And try to keepyour code fresh with the newest Python stoff.
